Angular Input Signals and sanitized values
I thought that I can use an URL as input Signal in my preview.component like
hrefLink = input.required<SafeValue>();

and in the .html use it like
<img [src]="hrefLink"/>

I have configured in my config.component.ts:
useLink:SafeValue;
...
initMethod() {
  this.useLink=this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
    myNavigationURL
  )

and use it in the config.component.html
<app-preview [hrefLink]="useLink"/>

But matter of fact I get an error saying:
 unsafe:[Input Signal: SafeValue must use [property]=binding

Do I miss something or is there a hole in the TypeCheck?

Please call the signal like below before sending to [src], we need to execute it, before sending it as an input to the src property binding!
import { Component, input } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeValue } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-preview',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<img [src]="hrefLink()"/>`, // <- changed here!
})
export class PreviewComponent {
  hrefLink = input.required<SafeValue>();
}

FULL CODE:
PREVIEW:
import { Component, input } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeValue } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-preview',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<img [src]="hrefLink()"/>`,
})
export class PreviewComponent {
  hrefLink = input.required<SafeValue>();
}

PARENT:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  DomSanitizer,
  SafeValue,
  bootstrapApplication,
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { PreviewComponent } from './app/preview/preview.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [PreviewComponent],
  template: `
    <app-preview [hrefLink]="useLink"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  myNavigationURL = 'https://placehold.co/600x400';
  useLink!: SafeValue;
  domSanitizer = inject(DomSanitizer);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.useLink = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      this.myNavigationURL
    );
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thx for the response - seems like the error is inherited with the usage of input-signals :-/  Anyway - thx for pinpointing and correction.
